# Use Django RedirectView with a named url dynamic

Tags: django, url, redirect

As I can do the following:

```
My url config
url(r'^video/show/(?P<slug>[-\w]+).html$', VideoDetail.as_view(), name="video_detail"),
to:
url(r'^video/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', Video.as_view(), name="video_detail"),
```

The first is the current url and I want to use Redirect to the second url config.

```
class VideoRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = True
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, slug):
        video = get_object_or_404(Video, slug__exact=self.kwargs['slug'])
        video.update_counter()
        return reverse('video_detail', args=(slug,))
```

as I can pass this on to the configurations of the urls. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?? What is the problem??

Comment: How to redirect > url(r'^video/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', Video.as_view(), name="video_detail"),

Comment: Why do they both have the same name?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had a similar problem whereby i wanted to dynamically redirect, whilst maintaining the kwargs.

Before I had a url like: /league/competition-name/video and I wanted all those requests redirected to /league/competition-name/all-video

within my urls.py

```
url(
    r'^league/(?P<competition>[0-9A-Za-z-]+)/(?P<tab>all-video|latest-news)/$',
    views.TabbedView.as_view(),
    name='competition'
),
url(
    r'^league/(?P<competition>[0-9A-Za-z-]+)/(?P<tab>video|latest)/$',
    views.TabbedPageRedirectView.as_view(),
    name='competition-redirect'
),
```

then within my views.py

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

class TabbedPageRedirectView(RedirectView):
permanent = True
query_string = True


def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['tab'] == 'latest':
        kwargs['tab'] = 'latest-news'
    if kwargs['tab'] == 'video':
        kwargs['tab'] = 'all-video'

    path = self.request.path
    path = path.replace('latest', 'latest-news')
    path = path.replace('video', 'all-video')

    self.url = path

    return super(TabbedPageRedirectView, self).get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

The trick was to build the self url from the self.request.path. I didn't find a way of doing this within the urls.py file